# Align x-axis label in morris bar chart

Tags: jquery, alignment, bar-chart, morris.js

I have a [Morris](http://morrisjs.github.io/morris.js) bar chart in which the `x` axis label is right aligned by default as shown in the figure:

[image: chart screenshot]

I want to align it on the center. How can I do this?

Here is my configuration code I used:

```
$.ajax({
    url: hostwithProtocol + '/Home/GetChartData' + "?startDate=" + startDate + "&endDate=" + endDate,
    type: "post",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (result) {

        for (var i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
            sLanding.push({u: (i + 1).toString(), a: result[i].Count, y: result[i].Referrer });
        }
        Morris.Bar({
            element: 'morris-area-chart',
            data: sLanding,
            xkey: 'u',
            ykeys: ['a'],
            labels: ['Count'],
            xLabelMargin: -25,
            padding: 50,
            barShape: 'soft',
            //hover callback function is here for getting the URL on hover
            hoverCallback: function (index, options, content) {
                var data = sLanding[index].y;
                return (data + content);
            },
        });
        $("#loader").css("display", "none");
        flag1 = 0;
    }
});
```

Comment: That looks fine, except the non existing `xLabelMargin` property. See if there isn't any CSS rule that interferes with it. Disable all CSS on that page and see if it displays correctly.

Comment: Disabling CSS does nothing to display correct chart

Comment: Adapting their [Morris.js Bar Chart Example](http://jsbin.com/uzosiq/258/embed?javascript,live) with your configuration shows ok to me: http://jsbin.com/bapowi/1

Comment: Your example is perfect but not working in my sample

Comment: That's why I believe the problem is somewhere else. Maybe I can help if you post some _(not all)_ more code that _(you believe)_ interacts with the chart.

Comment: @IulianOnofrei : I have updated the code. If I use your code in a separate file it displays the chart as I want but If I remove all CSS in my project and then add this code it still displaying the chart as shown in the picture. Don't know what's going on?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/73067/discussion-between-iulian-onofrei-and-twix).